# Sonata Admin Bundle and Doctrine issue: how to update an entity from inversed side?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities. Let's call those  `User` And `Group`.

I've decided that onto creation/update interface, because they could be associated, you can directly associate users from group form or groups from user form. Notice that the owning side of relation is `User`

Now comes the issue. If I associate groups from user form interface, all is good and works perfectly (doctrine looks for changes into owning side). If I try to associate `User` from group form interface, nothing works.

Obviously I perfectly know that I have to "add" user(s) into group object and add group (this) to every user(s) object that I passed down from form. In fact this is my snippet of code into `Group` entity

```php
public function setUsers(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $utente)
{
    /* snippet of code for removing old association , didn't reported */

    foreach($utente as $u){
        $this->users[] = $u;
        $u->addGroups($this);
    }
}
```

Into creation form this snippet do well his job. Into update, it doesn't.
So I suppose that this must be a sonata issue or something that, at the moment, I missed.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

After some time spent to understand what's going on here, I just find that `setUser()` isn't called into update operation (read as submit a form builded onto an existent entity). So my code runs only when I create new ones entry ( I still haven't a solution )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just find out how to update the entity.
I suppose that is a Symfony2 related behaviour and not a Sonata Admin one.

In a nutshell, you have to tell Symfony2 to call the setter of the object that you want to update.

For that use:

```
by_reference => false
```

In Sonata Admin Bundle case:

```
$formMapper
            ->add('nome')
            ->add('canali', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false))
            ->add('utenti', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false,
                                                       'by_reference' => false))
        ;
```

In pure Symfony2 Form case:

```
->add('utenti', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new User(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean that for update it does not do job well. Based on your code I assume it adds new relations between users and groups but do not remove old.

```
public function setUsers(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $utente)
{
    // to synch internal and external collections, remove relation between users and groups if user is not in the new collection
    foreach ($this->users as $u) {
        if (!$utente->contains($u)) {
            // add this function to user object, it's trivial, just remove give group from internal groups collection
            $u->removeGroup($this); 
        }
    }
    foreach ($utente as $u) {
        if (!$this->users->contains($u)) {
            $this->users[] = $u;
            $u->addGroups($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I miss the control where to add ONLY new user. But you totally miss the question: setUsers seems to don't work onto update operation

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your admin class

```
public function prePersist($group)
{
    $group->setUsers($group->getUsers());
    parent::prePersist($testQuestion);
}

public function preUpdate($group)
{
    $group->setUsers($group->getUsers());
    parent::preUpdate($testQuestion);
}
```